# How to improve Google Map Fragment v2 user location accuracy and smoothness like Google Maps application?

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have implemented Google Map Fragment into my Xamarin Android application. The map is working but the device's location (blue dot) is unstable and jumping around. Plus, the google map device's location (blue dot) is lag when in moving not as smooth as the Google Maps application.

My Question:-

1. Is this normal to have this laggy and unstable response in Google Map Fragment?
2. How can I improve the device's accuracy so I can produce much more stable and smooth user experience with the available sources?

Updated :-

Layout

```html
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/googlemap"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Activity

```
public class Test : Activity, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    GoogleMap mMap;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.test);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.googlemap);
    mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);            
    }

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.MyLocationEnabled = true;            
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but this could be a problem with your device. Sometimes some devices tell you that your GPS is inaccurate and you have to recalibrate it to increase the accuracy. I'd say it's worth testing on another device before trying to fix something that's not really a problem to begin with.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, until I have tested it. I run Google Map application on the same device it runs like a charm but when I run my application the map is unstable... it's like lagging and when I move the device the blue dot does not follow smoothly like in Google Map application.

Comment: It would be good to see some code which shows how you use the map. Otherwise it is all guesswork.